# Do connected devices affect throughput on internet

Tags: networking

I have been told by Hughesnet tech support that having multiple devices connected to their router adversely affects internet throughput to each device even if the devices are not turn on. (For example an audio receiver shows up as connected to the router).
They say bandwidth Is split to all connected devices whether or not they are actually using data or not. Is there any truth to this? If so would adding a router between the connected devices and the Hughesnet router reduce the draw down? There would only be one device connected not many.

Answer (score 1):

Without listing the make and model of your router, no answer can be 100% accurate, as they might be using some non-standard device.

However, that tech support person sounds like he has no idea what he is talking about or is lying for some reason.  The entire purpose of a router is to transmit data from one location to another efficiently.  If a device is off, a router will not send data to it, or expect to receive from it.  Even if the device is on, unless there is an *active* connection going to it, no data will be transmitted to/from the device.  A router can have any number of devices connected to it and the speed will not be reduced, unless there are multiple *active* connections running.

Comment: I agree with the above - I would note that devices which are connected - even if they are not using any bandwidth - could cause a problem due to limits in DHCP ranges.  Similarly a system with a lot of devices with active sessions could run into connection tracking problems - but neither of these should occur if the devices are off.